# Is it possible to easily implement a custom list VF page which works exactly as standard one does

Tags: visualforce, standardsetcontroller

My company wants to add a custom component(a header) at each tab page which is a list page.

There is no magic implementing the pageBlockTable. However, I do find implementing it with different views to be pretty hard. Is there any visualforce tags which can do the job or do I need to implement the whole stuffs manually?

Comment: Are you looking for [`<apex:enhancedList>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm)? It's hard to tell what you're going for exactly. Perhaps a screenshot would be most instructive.

Comment: [Useful cheatsheet](http://developerforce.s3.amazonaws.com/books/Visualforce-cheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be looking for how to implement what looks like an out of the box List View?

**Markup:**

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:enhancedList type="Account" height="400" />
</apex:page>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Account enhancedList]